# How to control two robot arm with one master

Tags: ros, motoman, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I have two set of Yaskawa Motoman MH5 with FS100 controller.

And now, I would like to control these two robot arm together.

Should I connect two robot arm to one controller or let them be separated ?

Please anyone give me some suggestion and tutorial.

Thanks a lot.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/317672/how-to-control-two-robot-arm-with-one-master/) by [A_YIng](https://answers.ros.org/users/40085/a_ying/) on ROS Answers with karma: 37 on 2019-03-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Do you need synchronised motion between the two MH5s?

Based on your answer to this, there will be two comparable, but slightly different answers (note: I'm assuming you want to use `motoman_driver`, if not, please clarify your question or ignore my answer):

1. If synchronised motion is not required: you don't need to connect them to the same FS100.

   As to the `motoman_driver` setup: you run **two** instances of the driver in separate ROS namespaces. Each `motoman_driver` instance would connect separately to each FS100. You would get two `FollowJointTrajectory` action servers, one for each controller.
2. If synchronised motion is required: you should probably connect them to the same FS100 and configure them as two motion groups on the controller.

   There would be a **single** `motoman_driver` instance that connects to the controller. No ROS namespaces would be necessary. You would see three `FollowJointTrajectory` action servers: one for each motion group and one for the combination of all joints. Sending trajectories to the per-group action server would result in async motion (ie: each manipulator is controlled individually). Sending trajectories to the "whole robot" action server would result in synchronised motion across all joints.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-03-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [A_YIng](https://answers.ros.org/users/40085/a_ying/) on 2019-03-06**:
Thanks for your reply, I exactly use motoman_driver in my project.
I would like to know how to connect two robot arm to the same FS100.
Any hardware should I get ?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-03-06**:
That would be something to ask your local Yaskawa branch office.

**Comment by [A_YIng](https://answers.ros.org/users/40085/a_ying/) on 2019-03-06**:
OK. I have the last question. Does [this](https://github.com/ros-industrial/motoman/tree/kinetic-devel/motoman_driver/Inform/DX200%2C%20FS100%2C%20YRC1000/two_arms) motoman_driver 'Inform' be suitable for this condition ?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-03-06**:
Probably. Perhaps @millete can add something here. It all depends a bit on how things are set up on the controller.